# How do i sort repeating decimals from non repeating decimals

Tags: python-3.x

Define a function called get_digits(n,d) which computes the digits of the decimal representation of the proper fraction n/d where you can assume that the numerator n is less than the denominator d.

The function should return a list consisting of two lists of digits. The first list is of all the digits that come after the decimal point which are NOT repeated (if any). The second list contains the digits that ARE repeated (if any). N must be less than d

For example:

```
get_digits(1,2) --> [[5],[]]
get_digits(1,3) --> [[],[3]] 
get_digits(1,8) --> [[1,2,5],[]]
get_digits(1,6) --> [[1],[6]]
get_digits(1,17) --> [[],[0,5,8,8,2,3,5,2,9,4,1,1,7,6,4,7]]
```

I have it so i can find values using normal division but I have trouble finding the 1/17 value here is my code:

```
def get_digits(n, d):
    a = str(n/d)
    b = a[2:]
    d = str("0123456789")
    ListOne = []
    ListTwo = []
    P1 = 0
    P2 = 1
    print(a)
    while P1 < 9:
        if b.count(d[P1:P2]) == 1:
            ListOne.append(d[P1:P2])
            P1 = P1 + 1
            P2 = P2 + 1
        if b.count(d[P1:P2]) > 1:
            ListTwo.append(d[P1:P2])
            P1 = P1 + 1
            P2 = P2 + 1
        if b.count(d[P1:P2]) < 1:
            P1 = P1 + 1
            P2 = P2 + 1
    print([ListOne , ListTwo])
```

get_digits(1,17)

Comment: This sounds like homework. What have you tried? What is your expected output? What is your actual output?

Comment: I have tried the code above but I have not gotten a result that matches a 1/17th output. This is homework but i have tried for several hours now with no results. I suspect my code only works for answers of single integer values for d

Comment: One suggestion, not an answer: Usually one can start by mimicing the manual process. If you are using the decimal string representation to separate the two, you have already lost vital information about this process. So, do the manual process on paper, observe yourself, and then mimic it in your program.

Comment: Are you saying to basically code long division? I have tried this method but I have trouble having the code recognize the repeated section. For example it is easy to have the code recognize 6 repeats in 1/6 but i have trouble having the code recognize 058823529411767 as a repeat in a 1/17th fraction.

Comment: Yes, I am saying that. And you need to keep track not of the digits that you produce, but of the dividends. So, in successive iterations the state of the program looks like [], [(0,1)], [(0,1),(5,10)], ...

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems legit.
Note few differences:

1. Cast at least one argument to `float`, so the result of the division will be float (as opposed to zero when dividing `int`s).
2. Use `string.digits` instead your `d` string (don't forget to `import string`
3. Loop on the with `for c in string.digits` instead of keeping those indices
4. The example output for `get_digits(1, 17)` at the top of your answer is wrong. (First hint is that digits appear twice in the second list)

Code:

```
def get_digits(n,d):
    a = str(n/float(d))[2:]
    listOne = []
    listTwo = []
    print(a)
    for c in string.digits:
        if a.count(c) == 0:
            continue
        elif a.count(c) == 1:
            listOne.append(c)
        else:
            listTwo.append(c)
        print([listOne, listTwo])
```

Comment: okay I agree that my 1/17 answer is wrong but when i input 1/17 into my code i get 3 6 and 9 to be non repeating which is false.

Comment: First, the result of the division is 0.058823529411764705.
My code's result: [['0', '3', '4', '9'], ['1', '2', '5', '8']]

Comment: This answer will not work. Firstly, the recurrent string may be longer than the string representation, and it may contain repeated digits. See OPs 1/17 example. It has many digits coming twice, and it is 16 digits. One can easily come up with much longer recurring digit sequences.